# Not able to get this union to work - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select' or 'as'

Tags: sql, union, crystal-reports-xi

I am modifying an Accounts Receivable Aging report. I have four tables

```
@archg(fgc, pvd, [date], archg) 
@arpay(fgc, pvd, [date], arpay)
@chg(fgc, pvd, [date], chg)
@pay(fgc, pvd, [date], pay)
```

What I need is to have combine the (archg and chg) to equal one total and (arpay and pay) to equal one total. I am not sure if I am going about this the right way. Any  help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select distinct
vp.person_name as pvd,
lfg.FinancialGroup_Code as fgc,
select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) 
    from @chg
    where  [date]<= 30
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 0-30
UNION
    select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg
    where  [date]<= 30
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 0-30;

select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) 
    from @chg  
    where [date] > 30
    and [date]<= 60
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 31-60
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 30 and [date]<= 60
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 31-60;

Select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) 
    from @chg  
    where [date] > 61 and [date]<= 90
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 61-90
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 61 and [date]<= 90
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 61-90;

Select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) 
    from @chg  
    where [date] > 90 and [date]<= 120
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 91-120
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 90 and [date]<= 120
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 91-120;

Select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) 
    from @chg  
    where [date] > 120 and [date]<= 150
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 121-150
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 120 and [date]<= 150
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 121-150;

Select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) 
    from @chg  
    where [date] > 150 and [date]<= 180
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 151-180
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 150 and [date]<= 180
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 151-180;
Select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) 
    from @chg  
    where [date] > 180 and [date]<= 365
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 181-365
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 180 and [date]<= 365
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 181-365;
Select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) 
    from @chg  
    where [date] > 365 and [date]<= 730
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 366-730 
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 365and [date]<= 730
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 366-730;
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 730
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 731+
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(archg,0)) 
    from @archg  
    where [date] > 730
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges 731+;
--  Select (sum(isnull(chg,0)) from @chg  
--      where fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Charges Total

Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay
    where  [date]<= 30
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 0-30
UNION
    Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay
    where  [date]<= 30
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 0-30;

Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay  
    where [date] > 30
    and datediff(day, date, @EndDate)<= 60
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 31-60
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 30 and [date]<= 60
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 31-60;
Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay  
    where [date] > 61 and [date]<= 90
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 61-90 
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 61 and [date]<= 90
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 61-90;
Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay  
    where [date] > 90 and [date]<= 120
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 91-120 
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 90 and [date]<= 120
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 91-120;
Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay  
    where [date] > 120 and [date]<= 150
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 121-150 
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 120 and [date]<= 150
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 121-150;
Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay  
    where [date] > 150 and [date]<= 180
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 151-180
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 150 and [date]<= 180
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 151-180;
Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay  
    where [date] > 180 and [date]<= 365
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 181-365 
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 180 and [date]<= 365
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 181-365;
Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay  
    where [date] > 365 and [date]<= 730
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 366-730 
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 365and [date]<= 730
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 366-730;
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 730
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 731+
UNION
Select (sum(isnull(arpay,0)) from @arpay  
    where [date] > 730
    and fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as pmt 731+;
--  Select (sum(isnull(pay,0)) from @pay
--      where fgc=lfg.FinancialGroup_Code and pvd=vp.person_name) as Pmt Total
into #AR
from
@chg, @pay, @archg, @arpay

order by
vp.person_name

--select * from @chg
--select * from @pay
--select * from #AR

select 
pvd as provider,
fgc,
isnull(isnull([Charges 0-30],0)-isnull([Pmt 0-30],0),0) as '0-30',
isnull(isnull([Charges 31-60],0)-isnull([Pmt 31-60],0),0) as '31-60',
isnull(isnull([Charges 61-90],0)-isnull([Pmt 61-90],0),0) as '61-90',
isnull(isnull([Charges 91-120],0)-isnull([Pmt 91-120],0),0) as '91-120',
isnull(isnull([Charges 121-150],0)-isnull([Pmt 121-150],0),0) as '121-150',
isnull(isnull([Charges 151-180],0)-isnull([Pmt 151-180],0),0) as '151-180',
isnull(isnull([Charges 181-365],0)-isnull([Pmt 181-365],0),0) as '181-365',
isnull(isnull([Charges 366-730],0)-isnull([Pmt 366-730],0),0) as '366-730',
isnull(isnull([Charges 731+],0)-isnull([Pmt 731+],0),0) as '731+'
--isnull(isnull([Charges Total],0)-isnull([Pmt Total],0),0) as 'Total'
--sum(isnull(isnull([Charges 0-30],0)-isnull([Pmt 0-30],0),0)+
--isnull(isnull([Charges 31-60],0)-isnull([Pmt 31-60],0),0)+
--isnull(isnull([Charges 61-90],0)-isnull([Pmt 61-90],0),0)+
--isnull(isnull([Charges 91-120],0)-isnull([Pmt 91-120],0),0)+
--isnull(isnull([Charges 121-150],0)-isnull([Pmt 121-150],0),0)+
--isnull(isnull([Charges 151-180],0)-isnull([Pmt 151-180],0),0)+
--isnull(isnull([Charges 181-365],0)-isnull([Pmt 181-365],0),0)+
--isnull(isnull([Charges 366-730],0)-isnull([Pmt 366-730],0),0)+
--isnull(isnull([Charges 731+],0)-isnull([Pmt 731+],0),0)) as 'Total'
from #AR
--group by pvd,fgc,
--[Charges 0-30],[Charges 31-60],[Charges 61-90],[Charges 91-120],[Charges 121-150],[Charges     --151-180],
--[Charges 181-365],[Charges 366-730],[Charges 731+],[Pmt 0-30],[Pmt 31-60],[Pmt 61-90],[Pmt     91-120],
--[Pmt 121-150],[Pmt 151-180],[Pmt 181-365],[Pmt 366-730],[Pmt 731+]
--order by 1,2

DROP TABLE #AR
```

Comment: What did you mean by "as Charges 0-30" - a single column called "Charges 0-30"? And why do you have a separate select/union for every column? Don't you just want to select all of the data into a single table?

Comment: I do need it in one table, however I a pulling money from the two differrent tables and putting the outcome as "charges 0-30" to be a column in the table #AR. Each "as charge or as pay is a different column" So I can subtract a charges 0-30 from pay 0-30 to get the AR. Hope I did not confuse you further.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. I should only union the two tables once, then break out the columns.

Comment: If you want to call your column "charges 0-30" then I think you need to wrap that in square brackets, [Charges 0-30], so it spots that that is the whole identifier. But your select and union return more than one result when you only actually want on for each row. I think you need to restructure the whole query, yes.

Comment: Could you give me a hint what that might look like the new query

Answer (score 2):

What you have looks very wrong to me, or at least WAY too complex. You should start over: decompose the problem and go step by step. I won't completely solve the problem, but this should get you started.

First, you want to combine 2 tables. OK, then start by combining them! E.g. for pay:

```
@pay(fgc, pvd, [date], pay) 
@arpay(fgc, pvd, [date], arpay) 

SELECT fgc, pvd, [date], pay from @pay
UNION 
SELECT fgc, pvd, [date], arpay as pay from @arpay
```

Similar for the other two tables.

Run the query and look at the results. You seem to want to group by certain date ranges. OK, so maybe we can add a property to group by:

```
SELECT fgc, pvd, [date], pay, 

CASE WHEN [date]<= 30 THEN '0-30'
     WHEN [date]> 30 AND [date] <= 60 THEN '30-60'
-- ETC, you get the idea
     ELSE '>730'
END AS daterange

from (
    SELECT fgc, pvd, [date], pay from @pay
    UNION 
    SELECT fgc, pvd, [date], arpay as pay from @arpay
) allpays
```

Run the query, look at the results. Small warning: it may be pretty slow as a full table scan will be required. But I'm mainly trying to illustrate a way of thinking here, you can optimize later.

OK, now you have something you can group by (fgc, pvd):

```
 SELECT fgc, pvd, sum(pay) FROM (
 -- insert the above subquery here
 ) querytogroup
 group by fgc, pvd
```

This can be joined with your entity tables (lfg, vp). And so on...

Comment: That you very much. I am trying to make changes to some elses query. Since she got it to work for one month I figured she knew what she was doing. Plus been a novice I was scared to start from the beginning. Taking a deep breath and starting a new. Thanks